# How to call a javascript when a page Rerenders?

Tags: javascript, rerender

I have a javascript function that I want to call whenever I do a page rerender using an apex:actionPoller. How can I best do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to call the JavaScript after the re-render use the `oncomplete` attribute of [apex:actionPoller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm) to make the function call:

> The JavaScript invoked when the result of an AJAX update
>   request completes on the client.